# Circulant matrix with integer entries and determinant 1 or -1

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, ac.commutative-algebra, set-theory

#### CONJECTURE

Let $A= (c_0,c_1,\ldots,c_n)$ be a circulant matrix, i.e if $(c_0,c_1,\ldots,c_n)$ is the first column of $A$ then the $i$<sup>th</sup> column of $A$ is obtained by applying the permutation $(1,2,..,n)^{i-1}$.

Assume $A \in GL_n(Z)$, i.e $A$ with integer entries and determinant $\pm 1$ and moreover $c_0+c_1+\ldots+c_n=\pm 1$.

Then there exists one $j$ such that $c_j=\pm 1$ and $c_i=0$ for all $i$ different from $j$.

---

Is this conjecture true?

What if we add the assumption that $n=p$ a prime?

Thanks for any idea!
Fabienne

Answer (score 7):

I think this is false.

Take the first row $A=(1,-1,1,-1,1,0,0)$.

The circulant matrix is:
$$
\left(\begin{array}{rrrrrrr}
1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 \\
-1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 1 \\
1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 \\
-1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right)
$$

The determinant is $1$.

Your definition is with columns, so you may need
to transpose.

---

Experimentally first row starting $(1,-1,1)$ followed by $n$ zeros
with determinant $\pm 1$
is [A047235](https://oeis.org/A047235)  `Numbers that are congruent to {2, 4} mod 6`

---

**Added** Solution with bigger $c_i$ is first row $(-2,6,-7,6,-2)$

Comment: A smaller example is the circulant with first row $1,-1,1,0,0$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Indeed. Working symbolically don't think counterexamples exist for n=3 or n=4.

Comment: There's a paper "Unimodular Integer Circulants" by John Cremona that studies this question in some depth: http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masgaj/papers/unicirculant.pdf

Comment: Regarding the "Experimentally" edit, for even $n$ the determinant is the product of $(1+w^3)/(1+w)$ taken over all solutions $w$ of $w^{n+3}=1$. If $\gcd(n,3)=1$, then the numerator and denominator run over the same numbers, so this product is 1.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your answers. I was convinced it was true. Is there a name for a matrix like a circulant but where the i-th column is a permutation f_i of the first column and  f_i not necessarily (1,2, ..,n)^i?